# Running Android apps on web browser

Tags: android, web, embed

I work for company which specializes in Native mobile app  development. The company does both Android and iOS apps. Now to show our apps to executives for different companies we use [pieceable.com](http://pieceable.com) to embed our iOS apps in browser. This way we can just send these potential customer an url and they can play around with the app.

After searching internet for a long time I couldn't find anything to do that kind of functionality for an Android app. Is there a way I can do it. Are there any tools which I can use?

Comment: Amazon has such a thing on their Appstore.

Comment: Amazon does have it but for that we need to post our apps to their market. Still a great comment.

Comment: Amazon so far looks like the closest match..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could run the App in an instance of the Android emulator, a VM which is part of the free [Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html).

Running the emulator in a regular VNC server session, rather than a VNC server App running on the emulator, would most likely provide better performance.

The VNC session and the Android emulator session could be started as needed from a web page with an embedded VNC viewer Java applet. On Ubuntu, for example, this is Java viewer client is freely available in the vnc-java package.

To avoid inadvertent data sharing between users, it would be necessary to run each VM session with a clean copy of the Android VM's AVD and virtual SD-card instance.

To reduce the VM copy and start-up time for the emulator sessions, it may be desirable to have the web server maintain a few active sessions started and ready for use. This would provide clean individual sessions for your potential customers to try.

Comment: Note that running the VNC server on the host rather than in the emulator may open this server up to some security issues, allowing users to get access to the host if, say, a window manager is started which processes special hot-keys.  Not that that is a deal breaker, just something to be aware of.

Comment: True - you'd want to run the VNC session as a low-privileged user and remove access to shells, etc.  It occurred to me, though, another distinct advantage to running the Android emulator within the VNC session is that it would give the user access to the virtual device buttons, such as volume, camera, etc.

Answer (score 9):

Maybe it's too late but checkout https://app.manymo.com/
They're running Android emulators in web browser. I think that is what you were looking for.

Answer (score 5):

Have you gone through [AppSurfer](http://www.appsurfer.com).

This site allows to run Android applications on the browser. In addition to that this product has a lot of more features like you can embed widget on your own site like you tube widget, and more interestingly the way you can play youtube video in facebook post, AppSurfer widget runs in facebook post itself without any redirection.

Give a try to this product.

Answer (score 4):

There really is no function to embed in a browser however you can have people download the app using their web browser. Just serve it from your server with the appropriate mime type and enable Unknown Sources loading on their phone. Look over the [publishing details](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html) minus the Android Market posting.

Comment: This involves people downloading our app and installing the .apk file. Its not the same experience as  pieceable.com where we literally sent the customers URL and also do a live demo via browser..

Answer (score 4):

An Android VM used to "come with" either [VMWare](http://www.pcworld.com/businesscenter/article/224561/vmware_to_ship_virtualization_clients_for_android_mac_os_x.html) or Paralle's... I forget which exactly.. - you just "selected it" under one of the application menus - and You could load it up right and quick, VNC into it, live networking, all the juice that a VM guest enjoys...  You could definitely rig something via that method, lacking another option....

In the same vein there is something like a [LiveCD installer project](http://code.google.com/p/live-android/) that I suppose does basically the same thing...  This would probably involve multiplexing the VNC session, or proxying the browser session,  somehow... but its definitely possible...

Oh, and don't forget the value of well-produced, concise and well-thought out "recorded" screencast demos..  You get to control the quality of the "experience", and it's prolly a whole heck of a lot easier...

Answer (score 1):

There are unfortunately no prepackaged solutions that do what you want. Your best bet would be to run an emulator instance with your app in it, and then patch in something like [Android VNC](http://code.google.com/p/android-vnc/). You can then use one of the browser-based VNC solutions (I believe [TightVNC](http://www.tightvnc.com/licensing-jviewer.php) has a java-based viewer that can be embedded as an applet).

Complex, but currently no real alternatives exist. Good luck.