# Simulate Android .apk files inside a browser

Tags: android, browser, compiler-construction

I recently visited this website -> http://appsurfer.com/apps/1-sudoku
And as you can see, It helps you simulate your android apps in the browser itself.

I know we can compile andoird-java code on the server side and show command line results to the user. But any idea how this simulation is being done ?

Any information would be very helpful.

Thank you.

Comment: This has been asked and answered before. Check this out [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6617183/running-android-apps-on-web-browser][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6617183/running-android-apps-on-web-browser

Answer (score 0):

You could run the emulator on a server and stream the display. If somebody clicks on the screen, map the click to the emulator. Interesting idea, I should try this out myself...

Comment: What if 100 people are parallely running different codes. Wont 100 emulators on the server be a bit too much for it to handle? We need to think of something to emulate it on the client side i feel ....

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to do something like this on the client! You should be able to run a few instancis at a time. If you have more users I guess a queue is the only option.