# How do I host an APK on a web browser?

Tags: android, web-services, sdk

I have a `.apk` app, and I wanted to convert it to a `website` to be played by signing in etc.

Usually people have used `PhoneGap`, but is there a reverse for that for android?

By reverse, I mean that given an `.apk`, I would like the code converted to a 
**microsoft visual studio** application that runs using a web browser.

Comment: I do not think it is possible but there are some of the apks that can be run in Chrome. you may take a look in it.

Comment: I am 100% sure it is possible.

Comment: Are you thinking of an Android Emulator in browser or via RDP? You may want to clear up what you mean by `microsoft visual studio application that runs using a web browser` See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6617183/running-android-apps-on-web-browser

Comment: No like host in a web server, using a hosting platform like MVS